# Conditions on a bounded Euclidean domain for the Lebesgue measure to be doubling

Tags: reference-request, partial-differential-equations, lebesgue-measure, geometric-measure-theory

Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be an open, bounded subset of a Euclidean space. Under what regularity conditions of the boundary of $\Omega$ the Lebesgue measure $\mu$ is known to be a *doubling measure*, i.e., it admits a constant $C>0$ (dependent only on $\Omega$) such that $\mu(\Omega \cap B(x,2r))\leq C\mu(\Omega \cap B(x,r))$ for all $x \in \Omega$ and $r>0$. I have read that "it is well-known" that the Lebesgue measure is a doubling measure on any domain with a Lipschitz boundary, but have found it extremely hard to find a precise theorem/proof of such a statement anywhere.

Comment: Did you miss an $\Omega$ on the RHS of your inequality? Otherwise it's wrong obviously hence LHS is bounded but RHS tends to $\infty$ for $r\to \infty$.

edit: also with an $\Omega$ the on the RHS it's kind of trivial…

Comment: Yes, you are right. That was silly of me. I will edit the question.

Comment: When you say 'universal constant', is that constant meant to be independent of $\Omega$?

Comment: Yes, dependent only on $\Omega$. I will edit this.

Comment: What if we have $\mathbb{R}^2$ and define
$\Omega = \cup_{n=1}^{\infty} A_n$ where each $A_n$ is an open annular region about the origin with outer-radius $1/n$, inner radius bigger than $1/(n+1)$ (to ensure $\{A_n\}$ are disjoint), and areas that satisfy 
$area(A_n) \geq n\sum_{k=n+1}^{\infty} area(A_k)$.   This does not have the doubling property since we can take sets near the origin with $B(x,r)$ inside the inner-radius of $A_n$, and $B(x,2r)$ contains $\cup_{k=n}^{\infty} A_k$ (so no constant factor $C$ works).  The boundary is a sequence of concentric circles, together with 0.

Comment: The result I was looking for follows from [Theorem 6.5, p. 28] in Pekka Koskela's thesis (Capacity extension domain): if $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is an $W^{1,p}-$extension domain, i.e., there exists a bounded extension operator $E : W^{1,p}(\Omega) \rightarrow W^{1,p}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ for each $n − 1 < p < \infty$, then there exists a constant $C > 0$ such that $\mu(\Omega ∩ B(x, r)| > C|B(x, r)|$ for all $x ∈ \Omega$ and all sufficiently small $r > 0$.